# Insert from XML into SQL Server table where node length exceeds 65000 chars?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

Could anyone help me get around the restriction (rewrite correctly the actual insert) on SQLType that can't be a 'text' type when you use the value fonction ?
(ref : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15 )

The 'notes' node in the xml down below will be more than 65000 char. If I leave it as is, it will truncate after 65000 char and ignore the rest.
changing it for : `MY_XML.mydata.query('NOTES').value('.', 'text')`  result in an error.

here is what I have, which works praticly for everything aside the 'text' column:

```
declare @myxml xml 

set @myxml = '<WebData>
  <Data>
    <ID>2003-0001</ID>
    <Number_1>2004</number>
    <NOTES> a huge chunk of text </notes>
  </Data>
</WebData>'

INSERT INTO myTable(ID,Number_1,NOTES)
SELECT MY_XML.mydata.query('ID').value('.', 'varchar(10)'),
MY_XML.mydata.query('Number_1').value('.', 'int'),
MY_XML.mydata.query('NOTES').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') 
FROM @monxml.nodes('/WebData/data') MY_XML(mydata)
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you are using `.value()` here in the first place.

Comment: Found out the query and made it work. I'm wasn't sure how to query an xml stats in the 1st place, and most exemple I found use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded a big text file from here:
https://www.sample-videos.com/download-sample-text-file.php

Its size is slightly more than 100K: **SampleTextFile_100kb.txt**.

And everything is working. Please see the T-SQL below.

Just don't believe your eyes. It is a limitation of the SSMS. It cannot show a large textual column.

The entire `<notes>` element textual value gets inserted into a table. The **notes_length** column shows its actual length.

Also, please pay close attention to the `SELECT` statement. It shows how to shred XML and convert it into a rectangular/relational format correctly.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID VARCHAR(10), Number_1 INT, notes NVARCHAR(MAX));
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<WebData>
    <Data>
        <ID>2003-0001</ID>
        <Number_1>2004</Number_1>
        <notes>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...
        ..., sed pharetra mauris vehicula vel.</notes>
    </Data>
</WebData>';
-- DDL and sample data population, end

INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, Number_1, notes)
SELECT c.value('(ID/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS ID
    , c.value('(Number_1/text())[1]', 'INT') AS Nmbr
    , c.value('(notes/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Notes
FROM @xml.nodes('/WebData/Data') AS t(c);

-- test
SELECT * 
    , LEN(notes) AS [notes_length]
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+----------+---------------------------------+--------------+
|    ID     | Number_1 |              notes              | notes_length |
+-----------+----------+---------------------------------+--------------+
| 2003-0001 |     2004 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,...  |       101854 |
+-----------+----------+---------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Ok, in my test I was stuck at 65000 char, but I never had the idea to check the lenght ! 
So it was a visual limitation. thanks alot for this !

I can't upload this a second time, but thanks for the simplification on the SQL query too. yours is alot more intuititive !